# Calling function from one class in another class

Tags: python, class, oop, user-interface, tkinter

Before I post my code, this is not all of it but what I feel is relevant to my problem. The first class is run when the user clicks a button, so the class contents (the frame) is displayed. The handler for my frames is:

```
class Begin(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # Creating the initial frame
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (LoginScreen, RegisterWindow, RevisionTopics, dataRep, reviseTen, FrameTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            page_name = LoginScreen.__name__
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

        self.show_frame(LoginScreen) # Shows the page currently being interacted
```

Now, this is the frame which has the important function, 'start', which I need to run in my second frame.

First frame:

```
class reviseTen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.startButton = tk.Button(self, text="Click here to start revision session", command = self.start)
        self.optionOne = tk.Button(self, text="Option One")
        self.optionTwo = tk.Button(self, text="Option Two")
        self.optionThree = tk.Button(self, text="Option Three")
        self.optionFour = tk.Button(self, text="Option Four")
        self.proceedButton = tk.Button(self, text="Proceed to next question", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(FrameTwo))
        self.question = tk.Label(self, text="What is the definition of: ")
        self.startButton.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def start(self): #This is what I wanna use in my second frame
        firstTime = True
        while firstTime:
            self.startButton.destroy()
            firstTime = False
        words = self.makeDict()

        initialListOne = ['Integer', 'Natural number', 'Rational numbers', 'Irrational numbers', 'Real numbers', 'Ordinal numbers', 'Binary', 'Hexadecimal']
        listOne = []
        for i in initialListOne:
            listOne.append(words[i])

        initialListTwo = ['Denary to Hex', 'Binary to Hex', 'ASCII', 'Unicode', 'Overflow error', 'Twos complement', 'Bitmapped graphics', 'Resolution']
        listTwo = []
        for i in initialListTwo:
            listTwo.append(words[i])

        initialListThree = [ 'Bit Colour Depth', 'Metadata', 'Sample resolution', 'Sample Rate', 'Audio file size', 'Nyquist Theorem', 'MIDI', 'Lossy Compression']
        listThree = []
        for i in initialListThree:
            listThree.append(words[i])

        initialListFour = ['Lossless Compression', 'Run Length Encoding', 'Dictionary compression', 'Encryption', 'Encryption steps', 'Caesar cipher',
                       'Brute force attack', 'Frequency analysis', 'Vernam cipher', 'One-Time Pad']
        listFour = []
        for i in initialListFour:
            listFour.append(words[i])

        listOfKeys = []  # Holds the keywords
        listOfValues = []  # Holds the definitions

        for key in words:
            listOfKeys.append(key)
            listOfValues.append(words[key])

        keywordPosition = random.randint(1, len(listOfKeys)-1)
        QKeyword = listOfKeys[keywordPosition]
        QDef = listOfValues[keywordPosition]


        self.question.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.optionOne.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.optionTwo.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.optionThree.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.optionFour.grid(row=4, column=0)
        self.proceedButton.grid(row=5, column=0)

        self.question.config(text=("What is the definition of: "+ QKeyword))

        randomOne = random.randint(0, len(listOne))
        randomTwo = random.randint(0, len(listTwo))
        randomThree = random.randint(0, len(listThree))
        randomFour = random.randint(0, len(listFour))

        selectButton = random.randint(1,4)
        if selectButton == 1:
            self.optionOne.config(text=QDef)
            self.optionTwo.config(text=listOfValues[randomTwo])
            self.optionThree.config(text=listOfValues[randomThree])
            self.optionFour.config(text=listOfValues[randomFour])
        elif selectButton == 2:
            self.optionOne.config(text=listOfValues[randomOne])
            self.optionTwo.config(text=QDef)
            self.optionThree.config(text=listOfValues[randomThree])
            self.optionFour.config(text=listOfValues[randomFour])
        elif selectButton == 3:
            self.optionOne.config(text=listOfValues[randomOne])
            self.optionTwo.config(text=listOfValues[randomTwo])
            self.optionThree.config(text=QDef)
            self.optionFour.config(text=listOfValues[randomFour])
        elif selectButton == 4:
            self.optionOne.config(text=listOfValues[randomOne])
            self.optionTwo.config(text=listOfValues[randomTwo])
            self.optionThree.config(text=listOfValues[randomThree])
            self.optionFour.config(text=QDef)

    def makeDict(self):
        dict = {}
        con = sql.connect("dataRep.db")
        cur = con.cursor()
        for column in cur.execute("SELECT keyword, definition FROM words"):
            variable = column[0]
            variable2 = column[1]
            dict[variable] = variable2
        return dict
```

Second Frame:

```
class FrameTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.optionOne = tk.Button(self, text="Option One")
        self.optionTwo = tk.Button(self, text="Option Two")
        self.optionThree = tk.Button(self, text="Option Three")
        self.optionFour = tk.Button(self, text="Option Four")
        self.question = tk.Label(self, text="What is the definition of: ")

    # TRIED THIS - screen stays blank (but start method has code that makes the widgets appear
        self.start(controller)

    def start(self, controller):
        self.reviseTen = reviseTen(self, controller)
```

I need start to complete the exact same functions as it did on the frame 'reviseTen', the function is running but just not doing anything to my second frame. It is just blank. The code for positioning the elements (so they show up) is meant to run after running start...

Is it to do with the way I called it?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Does `FrameTwo` need to do _exactly_ what is in `ReviseTen`? If it's exactly the same, why does it exist? Why not just use `ReviseTen` twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inherit `reviseTen` in your class instead of `tk.Frame`, and call the function with `super`:

```
class FrameTwo(reviseTen):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.optionOne = tk.Button(self, text="Option One")
        self.optionTwo = tk.Button(self, text="Option Two")
        self.optionThree = tk.Button(self, text="Option Three")
        self.optionFour = tk.Button(self, text="Option Four")
        self.question = tk.Label(self, text="What is the definition of: ")
        super(FrameTwo, self).start(controller)
```

For more info on `super`, check out some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods).

Comment: Which brackets? You mean parenthesis? If so, which parenthesis?

Comment: Glad I could help :)